# How to reference this path name in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following routes.rb

```
resource :user, :only => [ :edit, :update ] do
  collection do
    get :tax_info
    get :payment_info
    put :payment_info
```

and would like to reference the get payment_info via an rspec matcher like this:

```
      expect(response).to redirect_to(user_payment_info)
```

What would be the proper way to reference that path? I have tried `user_payment_info` and `edit_user_payment_info`?

#### Edit #1

Show output of `rake routes` on this controller

[image]

Comment: Post code, not images of code

Comment: Type `rake routes` in your terminal and you will get the path.

Comment: so rake routes gives the output above. the part that is wonky is that they are using get / put on the same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `_path` portion that rails generates for all routes. Your rspec matcher should look like this:

```
expect(response).to redirect_to(user_payment_info_path)
```

The information returned when running `rake routes` will look similar to this:

```
                  GET   /users/:id(.:format)         user#show
    tax_info_user GET   /user/tax_info(.:format)     users#tax_info
payment_info_user GET   /user/payment_info(.:format) users#payment_info
                  PUT   /user/payment_info(.:format) users#payment_info
        edit_user GET   /user/edit(.:format)         users#edit
             user PATCH /user(.:format)              users#update
                  PUT   /user(.:format)              users#update
```

You can see on the left hand side there is a column that denotes the prefix for the `url` and `path` helpers that rails is going to generate. [You can see this defined in the Rails 3.2 routing documentation.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/routing.html#paths-and-urls)

Comment: @timpone yw, happy to help :)